# Fastest way to iterate through a list/collection of objects in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

I have this code for a neural network library I am building

```
for connection in self.backwardConnections:
    self._z += connection.value()
```

where `connection` is a `cdef class Connection` and `backwardConnections` is python `list` of connections.

I have two question

1. What is the fastest iterate through a Python list? (I could have also done it with the typical `for int i in range (len (..))`)
2. If I abandon the python list approach, what collection type (e.g. numpy array, c++ vectors, etc) could hold my `Connection` objects and improve performance?

Comment: Are you doing more math with that list of values?  If so, you could make a `numpy` array of them, and operate on that.  e.g. `values.sum()`.  `numpy` also has a fast `nditer` iterator that works in `cython.

Comment: @hpaulj The thing is `connection.value()` is defined as `self.weight * self.source.y` where `source` is a `Neuron`, `y` and `weight` are `double`s. I am basically building a graph of the networks using neurons as nodes and connections as vertices. On thing I could do is have 2 cpp vector of pointers to the `w`s and `y`s, which one can iterate at c speed.

Answer (score 0):

The `for ... in ...:` construction is the fastest way to iterate over a list in Python. You will also not significantly improve performance by switching to another data type. These two things are already very fast.

My guess is that you are going about optimizing this code the wrong way. Instead of looking at the looping mechanism, which likely takes up an insignificant fraction of your running time, why not look at optimizing whatever the call to `.value()` does?

There's also the possibility that Python is just too slow for what you're trying to do. I find such cases to be quite rare, though.

Comment: `.value()` is actually pretty performant. But wait, are you aware that I am doing this in Cython? (with C).